# Qual a origem da expressão "voltar à estaca zero"?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica

Diz-se "voltar à estaca zero" quando um progresso é não só interrompido por algo ou alguma nova informação, como também requer recomeçar desde o começo (do zero) e replanejar, pois a forma como era feito o progresso se tornou agora obsoleto, inviável ou impossível.

Mas de onde veio essa expressão? O que é a "estaca" do "estaca zero"? Quando começou a ser usada essa expressão?

Comment: Estaca zero ([Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/estaca)), em topografia, é a estaca inicial de uma marcação topográfica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na construção de caminhos de caminhos de ferro no Brasil, marcavam-se com estacas o traçado da linha. A ***estaca zero*** era a primeira estaca, que marcava o início da linha. Daí que ***voltar à estaca zero*** viesse a significar recomeçar uma coisa desde o princípio.

Encontram-se no Google Books muitas referências a *estaca zero* a propósito do planeamento de caminhos de ferro no Brasil a partir do último quartel do século XIX (negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Dei começo á variante, partindo justamente da **estaca zero**, implantada pelos agentes da companhia para o respectivo ponto de partida
>   [*Estrada de Ferro D. Pedro I.: Parecer da Comissão Fiscal*, 1885.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=k6pAAQAAMAAJ&q=%22estaca%20zero%22&dq=%22estaca%20zero%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdntzPtJXbAhVKIMAKHbHECPAQ6AEILjAB)
>
> A extensão total dos trilhos assentados **entre a estaca zero e a ultima estaca**, além do gyrador em Araraquara, inclusive todos os desvios nas estações, monta em 51,093.73 metros correntes.
>   [Revista de Engenharia, Vol. 7, 1885.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=8K9BAQAAIAAJ&q=%22estaca%20zero%22&dq=%22estaca%20zero%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdntzPtJXbAhVKIMAKHbHECPAQ6AEINDAC)

Imagino que também se usassem estacas para estradas, linhas de telégrafo e coisas assim. Na verdade, o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/estaca), como apontou o Stafusa, e vários outros dicionários definem *estaca zero* como ‘a primeira estaca num levantamento topográfico’. Mas é sobretudo a propósito de caminhos de ferro que encontrei a expressão no sentido literal. Esta [Collecção das leis do Estado de Minas Geraes de 1895](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Ib8ReO7n7W8C&q=estaca&dq=estaca&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLtqL4rJXbAhUB0GMKHZIDBrkQ6AEIRDAE) sugere que as estacas na marcação de caminhos de ferro eram cravadas de 20 em 20 metros.

A mais antiga referência que encontrei a ***voltar à estaca zero*** no sentido figurado é de 1946, no Brasil. Pelo que o autor diz, a popularização da expressão devia ser recente:

> O inquérito teve início mas, como todos os inquéritos no Brasil, parou. Usando uma expressão muito em voga, **voltou à estaca zero**. Não sei o que isto quer dizer, mas penso que significa parar, porque encontrou obstáculos sérios que não convinha remover.
>   [*Mineração Metalurgia*, vol. 1(65-66), 1936.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1XolAQAAIAAJ&q=%22voltou%20%C3%A0%20estaca%20zero%22&dq=%22voltou%20%C3%A0%20estaca%20zero%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj60PHL0ZXbAhXB1hQKHVJHC8sQ6AEIjgEwEQ)

A partir desta data, o uso figurado de *estaca zero* é muito comum no Brasil. Fora do Brasil, o exemplo mais antigo que encontrei é de 1974 em Angola. Não tem o *voltar*, mas a noção de começar do princípio, do nada, está lá:

> **Estaca-Zero**, era a palavra pronunciada não há muito tempo pelas gentes que visitavam o Cuando Cubango [...] Queriam eles dizer que nada estava feito, além da fundação de Menongue, três ou quatro vilas e meia dúzia de postos administrativos.
>   [*O Turismo*, Centro de Informação e Turismo de Angola, 1974](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&biw=1242&bih=579&tbm=bks&ei=sJsCW82gEcy0tQXeyZygDQ&q=%22Estaca-Zero%2C%20era%20a%20palavra%20pronunciada%22&oq=%22Estaca-Zero%2C%20era%20a%20palavra%20pronunciada%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3917.6617.0.7005.2.2.0.0.0.0.96.176.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.47mL_jQ1Z6I), mais [outro excerto para completar](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&biw=1242&bih=579&tbm=bks&ei=ZpoCW_3LMuvWjwSWvIVI&q=%22Queriam%20eles%20dizer%20que%20nada%20estava%20feito%22&oq=%22Queriam%20eles%20dizer%20que%20nada%20estava%20feito%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21025.23925.0.24336.2.2.0.0.0.0.96.188.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.uQMM7AsZnMk).

A mais antiga que encontrei em Portugal é de 1988:

> Não acreditas então que os comunistas vão deixar de ter lugar no mundo moderno?
>
> Nem por sombras. **Voltámos à estaca zero**, mas já não é a primeira vez.
>   [(*Política Operária*, 16-32, 1988.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=roOzAAAAIAAJ&q=%22volt%C3%A1mos%20%C3%A0%20estaca%20zero%22&dq=%22volt%C3%A1mos%20%C3%A0%20estaca%20zero%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd_sDIzZXbAhWIyKQKHdEbAWcQ6AEIXDAJ)

Comment: Oi Jacinto, conhece? https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/

Comment: @Lambie, conheço e já me foi muito útil; tem material medieval que não encontras no Google Books. Também lá fui ver as estacas zero, mas neste caso o Google Books tem mais exemplos, e mais antigos.

Comment: Certo. O que me chamou a atenção foi que a frequência no pt-PT é maior do que no pt-BR.

Comment: @Lambie, É, mas é tudo dos anos 90, da imprensa. No Brasil, como acrescentei agora, o uso figurado de "estaca zero" é bastante comum desde os anos 40.